# Emacs: ido vs anything. Are they fighting each other?

Tags: emacs

I have been using ido-mode for months without issue.  I just recently decided to try `anything`.  It has many features similar to ido-mode.  However, `anything` now seems to be picking a fight with ido-mode.  I do a `C-x-f` and I see something that looks like the ido-mode stuff at the bottom but I also see some sort of `anything` buffer popup as well.  Did `anything` goon my ido-mode file selector?  If so, how do I tell and better yet, how do I turn it off?

Edit:  The anything buffer is titled `*anything-complete*`.  Turning off ido-mode doesn't give me a cool `anything` buffer when doing a `C-x-f`

Answer (score 5):

Yes!  They are fighting each other.  I found the following lines in anything-startup.el:

```
;;; anything-complete.el replaces various completion with anything
;;; (like Icicles). Use Anything power for normal completion.
(when (require 'anything-complete nil t)
  ;; Automatically collect symbols by 150 secs
  (anything-lisp-complete-symbol-set-timer 150)
  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map "\C-\M-i" 'anything-lisp-complete-symbol-partial-match)
  (define-key lisp-interaction-mode-map "\C-\M-i" 'anything-lisp-complete-symbol-partial-match)
  ;; Comment if you do not want to replace completion commands with `anything'.
  (anything-read-string-mode 1)
  )
```

"Anything power" neuters ido-mode power.  Toggling `anything-read-string-mode` helps, but it's an all or nothing switch.  Now, the completion for `M-x` went away.  I just want ido-mode for `C-x-f` and `C-x b`.  Does anyone have a way to turn off `anything-read-string-mode` only for those two features?

For now, I just add the following line to my .emacs:

```
;Be sure Anything does not fight with ido-mode.
(anything-read-string-mode 0)
```